# No source code available, catching exception in VS C++

Tags: visual-studio-2008, debugging, visual-c++

I'm testing my C++ code in VS 2008 (express) debug mode and my own class throws an exception. I've hooked visual studio to break when this particular exception is thrown. This usually works well and sends me to the line where the exception is thrown, along with the stack leading up to the error.

Sometimes though, VS gets stubborn and says there's no source code available when I'm trying to break debug execution. It asks if it may show the assembly instead, but that's really not much help to me anyway! It's clearly in my own code, since it's my own exception that's being thrown.

How can I get Visual Studio to recognize the "missing" source file again?

Answer (score 0):

I have only see VS do this when there is an uncommited Save in the source code file. Usually it asks you for the more recent.

Stop the code, save and then rerun.

Phil